# Can Artificers powers that target "weapon or implement" affect a Monks hand/feet?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk, artificer

Can the various Artificer powers that target `weapon or implement` be used to affect a Monks hand/feet attacks, even though they are not a weapon like a `Long Sword`?

**UPDATE**

Thinking on it, I suppose this is for both Monk attacks with their hand as a weapon, like `Melee Basic Attacks` and attacks when they use an actual `implement`

**UPDATE**
The `Weapon` reference in PHB2 and PHB3 makes it clear, `You can use an unarmed attack as your weapon`  [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=89)]

Comment: Could you mention an example power?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

The `Monk's Unarmed Strike` is considered a weapon. As is any other `Unarmed Strike` (1d4 no proficiency bonus, improvised one handed melee *weapon*). Therefore the powers that target a weapon could be used on the "monk's unarmed strike" weapon.

If they can also target implements they should be used on the `Ki Focus` with which the monk is channeling his powers.

Comment: Actually... anyone can perform an Unarmed Attack http://hastur.net/wiki/Unarmed_attack_(4E) and their hand/fist is considered a weapon.  Therefore the powers that target a weapon could be used on anyone's hand... not just a Monk's.  Correct?

Comment: Yes. Amending answer